Where do signals travel in a coaxial cable?
A quiz question I recently saw essentially states the following:

In an ideal coaxial line, a radiofrequency signal will travel only through the inner conductor.

A coaxial cable can be thought of as a waveguide with conducting walls. It's well known that the field in these kinds of geometries exists within the dielectric medium (air, vacuum, etc), not within the conducting walls. The fact that there is no field within the conductor is what determines the geometrical boundary conditions for each kind of waveguide (rectangular, circular, etc). Given this, wouldn't the electromagnetic wave within the coaxial cable travel through the dielectric medium between the two conductors?
Now if instead of introducing an electromagnetic wave within the cable we're talking about connecting it to a current or voltage source, then yes, the current signal travels through the inner conductor. But this is distinct from the RF electromagnetic wave, isn't it?
Is this just a matter of terminology, of referring to the current signal while actually saying "RF signal"?
EDIT: Literal translation of the question:

Theoretically, in a perfectly adapted coaxial line, a radiofrequency signal tends to travel:


a) Only through the outer conductor


b) Only through the inner conductor


c) Equally through both conductors


d) Far away from the dielectric


Please provide the full text of the quiz question. From what you said it sounds wrong, but I'd want to see the full text to be sure.

Check the edit.

As given, there's no question, just a statement of (possibly incorrect) fact. Are you supposed to judge it true or false, or is there a further question you are supposed to answer based on this statement?

I'm including the answer within the question. It's a multiple choice question where the answer is "only within the inner conductor".

What are the other choices?

Only within the outer conductor, equally between the two conductors and far away from the dielectric.

What topic are you studying? If this is about transmission lines in circuits (telegraphers equations, etc) then the best answer is probably "equally between the two conductors". If this is in an EM context then the question is bonkers and the answer should be "in the fields in the dielectric".

Please update the question to include the full text of the quiz question (including all the possible multiple choice answers) and then it will be answerable.

It's in a transmission line context, I think "between the two" is more correct since there is an incoming signal and a returning signal.

There was a similar question and answer session on Electrical Engineering Stackexchange, it is here, where The Photon answered it. Seems helpful.

For an impedance-matched coaxial line (source and load impedances both equal the line impedance) then the current through the inner conductor is equal to the current through the shield. In this case the shield current flows through its inner surface.
If there is an impedance mismatch between the cable and the load, part of the signal exiting the cable is reflected off the load. This current flows on the outside of the shield, and in the same direction as the current on the inner conductor. The sum of the inside and outside currents is equal to the current on the inner conductor.
All this is essential to understanding how to design and build transmitting antenna systems for amateur radio. The ARRL Antenna Book covers this in detail.

Can you back up the claim that reflected current signals flow on the outside of the shield? Does that mean a reflection from a mismatch produces no signal on the center conductor? How would it work if the feedline is a twisted pair line (where there's no "outside" and "inside")? Are you talking about any mismatch or maybe some particular situation (like where there's a unbalanced-to-balanced line transition)?

If the reflected current signal flows on the outside of the shield, And the sum of inside and outside currents is equal, where do the field lines associated with thej reflected voltage signal (presumably also emenating from the outside of the shield) terminate to?

Hello niels nielsen, In the case of "an impedance matched coaxial cable", does "the shield current flowing through its inner surface" satisfy Ohm's law?  If the answer is yes, does it cause the transmission energy loss of the coaxial cable?

So yes, the current signals may travel only through the inner conductor, what I wonder is if speaking of these as RF signals is frequent or not.

@ThePhoton, in that case the electric field lines go out to infinity i.e., the coax line starts to radiate and becomes part of the antenna. This creates problems for the radio operator and his or her equipment and must be avoided, hence the emphasis on proper impedance matching. .

@ HEMMI, each portion of the coax satisfies ohm's law and so there are always losses in the inner conductor and in both the inside and outside of the shield.

@agaminon, the effects I am discussing here are negligible at audio frequencies but dominant at RF frequencies.

I don't doubt that this is a real issue for antenna feeds, but it's not universal that reflected waves travel on the outside of the coax. If that happens, we can treat the region between the outer surface of the coax and "infinity" (and also to the nearby earth) as a third transmission line joining at the feedpoint of the antenna. We can then have reflected signals returning on both the coax structure, or the outer surface/earth structure. If 100% of reflected waves returned on the outer surface of the coax, a VNA would always read 0 reflection.
